# One javax.persistence.jdbc.url for windows and linux using firebird

Tags: java, hibernate, firebird

I want to use linux at work but everytime a class gets added to persistence.xml I have to change it's `javax.persistence.jdbc.url`.

Is there a way to make hibernate use one property for windows and another one for linux without creating two files?

windows is like C:/blah/db.gdb and linux is /home/blah/db.gdb
how can we use one for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an alias on the server in `aliases.conf` (`databases.conf` in Firebird 3 and higher), and then specify that alias in the connection url instead.

Say that the alias is `myApplicationDb`, then you can use the URL:

```
jdbc:firebirdsql://myserver/myApplicationDb
```

However this is less flexible because it requires you to maintain the `aliases.conf` file.